# Need help in representing disjunction in English statement

Tags: logic, quantifiers

Suppose I have a predicate, `Ex (P(x) ^ Q(x))`.

**EDIT:**

Sorry it was,

```
Ex (P(x) V Q(x)).
```

I made its English statement,

> There is atleast one x for which P(x) or Q(x) is true.

Do I have to mention that if both of them are true then also the statement would be true?

Comment: English is slippery.  Many people in many contexts (some people in some contexts-logically the same but different feeling) interpret "or" as exclusive or.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I think the usual notation for disjunction is $\vee$. $\wedge$ usually means "and".

Also, the term "or" as in $A \vee B$ is defined as follows :

A is True, B is True, then $A \vee B$ is True

A is True, B is False, then $A \vee B$ is True

A is False, B is True, then $A \vee B$ is True

A is False, B is False, then $A \vee B$ is False.

Therefore the term "or" (in this context) already includes the case when both are true. So for your expression $(\exists x)(P(x) \vee Q(x))$, it suffices to translation as follows :

There exists an $x$ such that $P(x)$ or $Q(x)$.

In this context, most people will understand the intended meaning of the "or".

Comment: Sorry, I wrote ^ by mistake. It meant OR. Thanks.